# Getting back data in a Pandas DataFrame after a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df` with informations about elements, for instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,45,12],[1,8,13],[1,3,4],[2,5,1],[2,7,3]], 
                  columns=['group', 'value1', 'value2'])
```

I have used something like `dfGroups = df.groupby('group').apply(my_agg).reset_index()`, so now I have `dfgroup`, say

```
dfGroup = pd.DataFrame([[1,4],[2,27]], 
                      columns=['group', 'valuegroup'])
```

Now I need to bring back the group information to the elements, to be able to build new columns taking into account elements data and group data. So to make it simple, let's say I need to build a `valuegroup`column in `df` identical `dfGroup` data. So I would obtain

```
    group   value1  value2  valuegroup
0   1       45      12      4
1   1       8       13      4
2   1       3       4       4
3   2       5       1       27
4   2       7       3       27
```

What's the best way to do that? (If possible, something that would work with Python 2 and 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].transform(my_agg)
```

Or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df, dfGroup, on='group', how='left')
print (df)
   group  value1  value2  valuegroup
0      1      45      12           4
1      1       8      13           4
2      1       3       4           4
3      2       5       1          27
4      2       7       3          27
```

Or if omit `reset_index` is possible use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
dfGroups = df.groupby('group').apply(my_agg)
df = df.join(dfGroups, on='group')
```

Sample:

```
dfGroup = pd.DataFrame([4,27], 
                      columns=['valuegroup'], index=[1,2])

print (dfGroup)
   valuegroup
1           4
2          27

df = df.join(dfGroup, on='group')
print (df)
   group  value1  value2  valuegroup
0      1      45      12           4
1      1       8      13           4
2      1       3       4           4
3      2       5       1          27
4      2       7       3          27
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for your detailed answer! I'm approving this, and I'll use join, since I actually need several columns from the group df, so it's easier to use than cstainbrook's solution, which is nevertheless very good.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.set_index('group', inplace=True)
dfGroup.set_index('group', inplace=True)
df['valuegroup'] = dfGroup['valuegroup']
```